# How does converting float to double work?

Tags: c, floating-point, double, ieee-754, single-precision

double can represent every value a float can represent.

Does converting float to double simply extend the mantissa by adding 0 and extend the exponent part by filling sign bits?

I tested some data at http://www.binaryconvert.com/index.html. It works in this way. But I did not find any official definition of the conversion. Does the conversion have any corner case not working this way?

Comment: I think you're asking about IEEE-754 (the most common floating-point format), not the C language.  The latter has essentially nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 6):

This has very little to do with C; its only guarantee is that converting from `float` to `double` must preserve the value.

So you're really asking about (presumably) [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).  There are at least a few ways in which your description doesn't hold:

1. The exponents for single-precision and double-precision have different biases.  So conversion requires more than just sign extension.
2. Denormal numbers require special handling (they become normal numbers).
3. NaNs may also require special handling - distinguishing between signalling and quiet NaNs is dependent on the value of the mantissa.

Comment: Given a float value, can we still know it is a denormal number or normal number? I had thought all denormal numbers are rounded into the closest normal number. And all normal numbers in float must be normal in double.

Comment: Could you please give an example of the bias issue at exponents part?

Comment: @JoeC - The exponent is defined as always positive.  It's possible that the conversion works out equivalent to sign extension, but I haven't thought it through fully ;)

Comment: @JoeC - If the exponent is zero and the mantissa is non-zero, then it's denormal.